# How do I create a dataframe from another dataframe with only the last non negative values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization, multi-index

I have a multi-indexed dataframe like so:

```
          year  value  some_other_column_i_dont_care_about
 one two     
 a   t     2000     0   aaa
     w     2001     3   bbb
     t     2002    -2   ccc
 b   t     2000     4   ddd
     w     2001     7   eee    
     t     2002    -8   fff
 c   t     2000    11   ggg
     w     2001   -12   hhh
     t     2002   -15   iii
```

How do I create a new, single level df, that just has the latest (in terms of years) non-negative values, like so:

```
          year   value
 one    
 a        2001     3
 b        2001     7
 c        2000    11
```

Comment: I changed the wording of my question, to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: What does "latest" mean? :) 
Just do `df1 = df.loc[(df['value'] > 0) & (df['Year']>2000)]`  or 
`df1 = df.loc[df['value'] > 0]`, then `df1.sort_values('year')` to order by year

Answer (score 2):

Create a Boolean index for values greater than or equal 0 then use [`groupby last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-last):

```
m = df['value'].ge(0)
new_df = df[m].groupby(level=0).last()
```

If the years aren't guarenteed to be sorted in ascending order, chain in a [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-values)

```
new_df = df[m].sort_values('year').groupby(level=0).last()
```

`new_df`:

```
     year  value
one             
a    2001      3
b    2001      7
c    2000     11
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'one': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
    'two': ['t', 'w', 't', 't', 'w', 't', 't', 'w', 't'],
    'year': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2000, 2001, 2002],
    'value': [0, 3, -2, 4, 7, -8, 11, -12, -15]
}).set_index(['one', 'two'])

m = df['value'].ge(0)
new_df = df[m].groupby(level=0).last()

print(new_df)
```

Comment: Wow! Can I do this for multiple columns at a time, if say, I had several value columns, i.e. value1, value2, value3... etc?

Comment: Like, would this work:                                                                                                     m = df[['value','value1','value2']].ge(0)
new_df = df[m].groupby(level=0).last()

Comment: I mean, yes? It kind of depends what you mean by do this for multiple columns at a time. You can add whatever conditions you want to the mask and it'll work. So for example if you wanted the last row where value1 was positive _AND_ value2 was positive `m = df['value1'].ge(0) & df['value2'].ge(0)` would work.

Comment: No you'd have to use some extra Boolean logic. Either the `&` listed above, or `m = df[['value1', 'value2']].ge(0).all(axis=1)` But then it should work.

Comment: What if I wanted the latest non-neg value for each value column independent of the other value columns?  Thats my goal....

Comment: That's kind of a different question than the one you've posed in this thread. I would recommend you post a separate question outlining the multiple values columns and your expected behaviours.